# Append accessor on demand

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, accessor

I am trying to *sometimes* append my *Accessor* to the result of a *Eloquent* query.

Here is my accessor:

```
public function getCatAttribute() {
    return "Here's a cat!";
}
```

If I append it using the `protected $appends = array('cat');` array, it loads it just fine every time.

However, when removing that as I don't want it to always append it, I can't get it to load it on the *Eloquent* query.

Here's what I tried:

```
$items = Item::with('cat')->get();
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Accessors are not appended to any query. They are processed during `toArray`/`toJson` call if you use `$appends` property, that's all. So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to add the *Cat* attribute in some cases, and not in others

Comment: Well, obviously.. You're not specific, so you want others to guess? Now I can only tell you: create logic that SOMETIMES returns mutated value, otherwise returns it intact.

Comment: The question is specific. *I am trying to sometimes append my Accessor to the result of a Eloquent query, how can I achieve this?*

Comment: And I am aware I will need to "create logic" that does what I am asking

Comment: That's pretty straight forward: `return ($sometimesCondition) ? $mutatedValue : $value;` and use `$appends` property. Other than that, that *sometimes* is the key here to suggest specific solution. In general - Eloquent is not capable of using accessor only sometimes by itself, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if I'm late for the party.

You can't do:

```
$items = Item::with('cat')->get();
```

because the accessor is a computed property, which means it needs to have the actual properties from the model instance first.

Instead, you can do this:

```
$items = Item::get();
$items->append('cat'); // this allows you to append accessors on-demand
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

IMO only way to do it, is extend your model class and use `$appends` as you already mentioned. So something like

```
class ModelWithCat extends MyModel
{
    protected $appends = ['cat_attribute']
}
```

and then call it as

```
ModelWithCat::get();
```

**Below is my old answer for reference:**

I was sorting similar issue, in my case I needed to feed the JSON data from query builder to a Vue table and needed to transform the data in back-end, so vue table can use the data directly. My code in controller looked like this:

```
$query = Photo::query()->with(['user']);
if($filter) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', "%{$filter}%")
}
return $query->orderBy($field, $dir)->paginate($limit)
```

I haven't found a way to trigger accessor for the collection, and I couldn't loop through the result of Paginator class. Finally I realized this is returning JSON in the end, which I can modify before sending to Vue. So I ended with something like this:

```
// transform the data before return them
$res_json = $query->orderBy($field, $dir)->paginate($limit)->toJson();
$res_decoded = json_decode( $res_json );
foreach($res_decoded->data as $item) {
    // transform the data.. you could probably call your accessor here like 
    // $item->cat = $item->cat , for me it was easier to just write the logic
    // here instead
    $item->license = 'dynamic-license';
}
return response()->json($res_decoded);
```

I know it's ugly, but it was the only way I found and I am using it at one place only, so I reckon I have to live with that. Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late post but for some others who want to get idea, simple ways to achieve on demand IMO in latest version, using append method on query call. It's already in some of the above answer.

```
Item::get()->append('attibute_name');
```

Plus, when working with pagination

```
$paginate = Item::paginate(10); // receive LengthAwarePaginator Instance
$items = collect($paginate->items()); // receive paginated items only to append
$items->each->append('attribute_name') // then simply you append it what auto accessor will do in toArray()
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand the issue but you may create accessor for not existing attribute. Assuming you have `cat` attribute, you may create:

```
public function getModCatAttribute($value) {
  if ($this->cat == 'dog') {
     return "I'm a dog";
  }
  return $this->cat;
}
```

so you can access now `$model->cat` and `$model->mod_cat`. For general usage this method is better because you will have always access to original property and for the modified one and you always know which one is modified.

But you can also do it this way:

```
public function getCatAttribute($value) {
  if ($this->cat == 'dog') {
     return "I'm a dog";
  }
  return $this->cat;
}
```

And now you can access `$model->cat` and  result rely on what you have inside your `$cat` attribute.